# Application - JMenuBar for all forms

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am new to Java. I have programming experience on other programming languages , especially in PowerBuilder. I am writing a Java application with many forms and reports. I want to have a menu common for all forms and reports (any window on my application).

I thought I could create a basic mainframe with the menu on it and the open any other window inside this main frame. I can't figure this out , only with internal frames but this is not what I want.

I made my `JMenuBar`, I put it on `JPanel` and then I put panel on a maximized `JFrame` I called `mainframe`. Any window from menu bar opens in front of `mainframe` frame. When I click on `mainframe` any open window goes back of course, focus is on the `mainframe`.

I wrote a `MouseListener` for panel which brings any open window `toFront` except `mainframe` of course. That seems to make the job but I have to write the same listener for the menu bar and this has the disadvantage of windows "flashing" any time they are coming to front.

My questions are:

- What is the way you work with menu bars?
- Do I have to put menu bar to any form I create?
- How can I have a main frame (maybe maximized) with the menu bar on it always on back and any other window opens in front of this frame?

What I really need is a main frame with menu for my application and everything happens inside this frame.

Comment: code will speak better then words here, I guess.

Comment: From what i´ve read you add the `JMenu` to the `JPanel`, but it should be added to the `JFrame`

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: *"only with internal frames but this is not what I want."* Why ***not*** use a `JDesktopPane` & `JInternallFrame`s?

Comment: *"How can I have a main frame (maybe maximized) with the menu bar on it always on back and any other window opens in front of this frame?"* If the frame(s) were instead dialog(s) that passed `mainFrame` as the parent, that would happen automatically.

Comment: I added the JMenuBar to a JPanel and then edded the JPanel to a JFrame because I wanted to write a mouselistener on JPanel which brings toFront any active window except the mainframe.

Comment: "Why not use a JDesktopPane & JInternallFrames? "
I think I have more flexibility with JForms but I  will give a try to JInternallFrames
The solution with mouselistener who brings any window front seems to work but I have to write a mouse listener for jmenubar too.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'd take a closer look at [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: Tip: Add @YoungHobbit (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"I think I have more flexibility with JForms"* Stop talking like your IDE. There is no such thing in the J2SE as a `JForm` - if you mean a `JFrame` then **write that!**

Answer (score 0):

I will work with InternaFrames finally

Thanks a lot